# Weird behaviour, array is empty when trying to delete an item

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

So, I fetch some items to my db, I place them in my Adapter, but when trying to delete it , the size of the list is 0 , thats weird because when I tap an element to delete the list is actually populated with some items

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        fetchProducts(shopId)

        rv_myshop.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        rv_myshop.addItemDecoration(
            DividerItemDecoration(
                requireContext(),
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
            )
        )
    }

 private fun fetchProducts(shopId:String){
        viewModel.fetchProducts(shopId).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { result ->
            when(result){
                is Resource.Loading -> { showProgress() }
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    hideProgress()
                    adapter.setItems(result.data)
                    rv_myshop.adapter = adapter
                    if(adapter.itemCount == 0){
                        container_no_products.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Failure -> { hideProgress() }
            }
        })
    }
```

Until here all is working fine, this code just brings up my data and populate my list ! Nice, but now, I try to delete an item pressing my delete button in my adapter and the items are not deleted from the array and the array shows 0 items, when it has more items...

```
  override fun onDeleteProductClick(position: Int) {
        adapter.removeItem(position)
}
```

### MyAdapter

```
  var productsList = mutableListOf<Product>()

    fun setItems(productsList:MutableList<Product>){
            this.productsList = productsList
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        fun removeItem(position: Int){
            productsList.removeAt(position)
            notifyItemRemoved(position)
        }
```

So, here when I try to `removeItem` it does not remove anything because the list appears to be of size 0, but I have actually set that list before with `setItems`

Im lost, I have debugged the program and that list shows 0 in size when I already fetched the values

any hint ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in my dataSource I was modifying this item, so I just needed to notifyDataSetChanged at the result of my deletion